# Как убрать повторяющиеся пробелы и знаки табуляции?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Как убрать повторяющиеся пробелы и знаки табуляции, оставить по одному пробелу между словами и по два между предложениями.

Например:

`Extra       spaces` => `Extra spaces`

`Sentence.      Sentence.` => `Sentence.  Sentence.`

Comment: регулярные выражения они и в Африке регулярные дай вариант как они пишутся в java и часть текста конкретно вид предложения попробую реализовать

Comment: `str.replaceAll("[\t ]{2,}", " ");` - 2 и более символов пробела и/или табуляции заменить на 1 пробел

Comment: @PotroNik о, я тебя знаю)

Answer (score 0):

Делаешь цикл, итератор начиная с нуля до конца строки.
Проходишься по каждому символу строки, и проверяешь если строка[i] == ' ' и строка[i+1] == ' ', тогда удаляешь символ i из строки

Answer (score 0):

См. [Регулярные выражения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F):

```java
String str = "Sentence.      Sentence. \t Extra       spaces,     o!";

String str2 = str
        // последовательности (1 и более)
        // пробельных символов
        // заменяем на один пробел
        .replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
        // последовательности (1 и более)
        // пробельных символов в конце
        // предложения (после точки '.')
        // заменяем на два пробела
        // (точку '.' оставляем на месте)
        .replaceAll("(\\.)(\\s+)", "$1  ");

System.out.println(str2); // Sentence.  Sentence.  Extra spaces, o!
```